# javascript convert json to object

Tags: jquery, json

This code fails

```
var data = '{ "name": "binchen" }';
data = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(data.name);//throws undifined
```

This code works

```
 var data = { "name": "binchen" };              
 alert(data.name);
```

How do I convert data into an object in the first scenario?

Comment: Headline? JSON is a string - ALWAYS. If it's not a string it's not JSON. WHy are you trying to stringify a string???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON string into a JavaScript *object* (there's no such thing as a "JSON object", JSON is a string based exchange format) :

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: That worked! I will mark it as soon as it lets me. Thank you !